# Jquery plugins within AJAX loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I'm using Django, the tabs described afterwards are loaded with `render_to_response` and the html response is set on the `success` method of the AJAX call.

Process:

- I have my page with tabs. In order to avoid loading all tabs, they're loaded dynamically (with AJAX)
- This main page have its custom javascript file
- In a loaded div, when clicking a button, I have a pluggin, fancytree, which is called on a div. Both tabs have their own custom javascript **plus** the one of the main page described in the first point.

Here's a diagram which, I hope, will help you to understand :

```
mybase.html
     ---> mybase.js

     ------- AJAX Loaded -------> mytab1.html <-------------
                                     --> mytab1.js -------| (*1)

     ------- AJAX Loaded -------> mytab2.html
                                     --> mytab2.js

     ------- AJAX Loaded -------> mytabn.html
                                     --> mytabn.js
```

(*1) : In `mytab1.js`, I have a portion of code which use the pluggin `fancytree` formatted
as a JSON string.

ie :

```
base.js : 
$('document').ready(function(){
   $('#someTab').on('click',function(){
        $(this).html(loadSomeAjax());
   });
});

mytab1.html : 
<div id='my_fancy_tree'> // Some JSON here </div>

mytab1.js : 
$('document').on('ready ajaxComplete',function(){
     $('#my_fancy_tree').fancytree({ // params here });
});
```

My question is very simple, how to make the pluggin fancytree works ? I tried various things, read a lot of docs but unfortunately, never figured out how to do.

Comment: well you have the ending commented out... try and remove that comment // params here

Comment: It's not commented, It's just a way to say that I put my parameters here (there's about 100 code lines and I won't put it on the thread, it would take too much space ;) )

Comment: do you get an error in the console?